# How to submit another get attribute and keep previous one?

Tags: java, jsp, get

I'm building my first web app in Java. I came across this problem. When I have a get attribute like ?page=2 correctly submitted it goes missing after calling another get request. How can I keep the first one and append another one? Here are pics that help clear out my question

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SCmU.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ngH.png)

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBmMi.png)

Here are code snippets of my forms in .jsp page. This is used to sort the table with passing a column name:

```
                <form action="GetUsersServlet" method="get">name
                    <input type="hidden" name="column" value="name">
                    <button class="sort" type="submit"></button>
                </form>
```

How can I append the value to existing ?page=x attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Use `URLSearchParams` method set on event `click` and set `window.location.search` to parsed params.

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
   const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
   urlParams.set("page", 2)
   window.location.search = urlParams.toString()
}
```

Comment: Alright, but what should I do to append this second attribute to the first one? Each time I'm calling either of them, first one vanishes from my URL and it's replaced by second one

Comment: Thanks, that might be useful later on, but that's still not what I have trouble with. Let's take a situation as an example. I have my attribute ?column=name already in URL, which means I have my table sorted by this column. I would want to go to second page of the table, which corresponding button is at the bottom of the website. How can I go to second page (append &page=2) to already existing attribute (?column=name)?